# PHP equivalent jagged arrays in C#

Tags: c#, php, arraylist, multidimensional-array

In PHP5 i have declared some arrays as

```
$secArray0 = array();
$secArray1 = array();
$secArray2 = array();
$secArray3 = array();
$secArray = array();
```

Later on some where in the code I insert key-value pair in the above arrays as

```
    $pHolder0 = array(
    'Name'   => 'Gomesh',
    'EmpCode'   => 'ID04',
    'DeptId'     => '1C',
    'Age'=> '25'
);
array_push($secArray0,$pHolder0);
```

And so on for $secArray1, $secArray2, $secArray3.

And finally I insert $secArray0,$secArray1....$secArray3 inside $secArray as

```
$secArray = array($secArray0,$secArray1,$secArray2,$secArray3);
```

Now my question is can I accomplish such thing in C#?

So far I have done..

```
var secArray0 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
secArray0.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "gomesh"));
secArray0.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmpCode", "ID04"));
secArray0.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DeptId", "1C"));
secArray0.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Age", "25"));
```

And so on up-to secArray3. But how do I insert secArray0,secArray1,secArray2,secArray3 inside secArray? Just like the PHP code explained above.

Comment: Use a [`Dictionary<string, string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `secArray0` and a `Dictionary<string, string>[]` for `secArray`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit elaborately how to do ....Dictionary<string, string>[] for secArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<string, string>` for `secArray0` and a `Dictionary<string, string>[]` for `secArray`:

```
var secArray0 = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Name", "gomesh" },
        { "EmpCode", "ID04" },
        { "DeptId", "1C" },
        { "Age", "25" }
    };

...

Dictionary<string, string>[] secArray =
    {
        secArray0,
        secArray1,
        ...
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var secArray = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var secArray0 = new Dictiionary<string, string>();

secArray0["Name"] = "Gomesh";
secArray.Add(secArray0);
```